# Navbar button won't drop down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm a junior web developer and I'm struggling with my dropdown button. When I resize the screen to test it, it won't drop down. Thank you!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50?text=Logo" alt="">
        </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="form.html">Sign In/Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you make sure you adding the boostrap CDN scrips and links in your page `head` - what do mean by wont go down. Its is working perfectly. Can you clarify the problem please

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare this?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Yes I did but now it won't stay extended, it collapses itself as soon as I click it. It shows for like 1 second then it disappears

Comment: fixed, needed to declare the bootsrap js bundle. Thank you very much!